# Joining second table in query doesn't return anything in wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have search field on the page which is default wp field I think. When I hit search button it is searching properly from the `posts` table and show all results.

Now I want to join second table from where to search also and show results from there if there is any.

So in the `function.php` file in the theme folder I have added this:

```
function vh_search_meta_data_join($join) {
     global $wpdb;

    // Only join the post meta table if we are performing a search
    if ( get_query_var( 's' ) == '' ) {
        return $join;
    }

    // Only join the post meta table if we are on the Contacts Custom Post Type
    if ( !in_array('videogallery', get_query_var( 'post_type' ) ) ) {
        return $join;
    }

    // Join the post meta table
    $join .= " LEFT JOIN ".$wpdb->prefix."hdflvvideoshare";

    return $join;
}

function vh_search_meta_data_where($where) {
    global $wpdb;

    // Only join the post meta table if we are performing a search
    if ( get_query_var( 's' ) == '' ) {
        return $where;
    }

    // Only join the post meta table if we are on the Contacts Custom Post Type
    if ( !in_array('videogallery', get_query_var( 'post_type' ) ) ) {
       return $where;
    }

    // Get the start of the query, which is ' AND ((', and the rest of the query
   $startOfQuery = substr( $where, 0, 7 );
   $restOfQuery = substr( $where ,7 );

   // Inject our WHERE clause in between the start of the query and the rest of the query
   $where = $startOfQuery . "(" . $wpdb->prefix."hdflvvideoshare.description LIKE '%" . get_query_var( 's' ) . "%') OR " . $restOfQuery ." GROUP BY " . $wpdb->posts . ".ID";

   // Return revised WHERE clause
   var_dump($where);
   return $where;
}
```

When I add this it doesn't return anything neither from posts nor from  hdflvvideoshare. It's showing me `"No results"`.

`var_dump($where);` return this:

```
string(625) " AND (((wpdu_hdflvvideoshare.description LIKE '%driver%') OR (((wpdu_posts.post_title LIKE '%driver%') OR (wpdu_posts.post_content LIKE '%driver%'))) OR ((tter.name LIKE '%driver%')) OR ((tter.slug LIKE '%driver%')) OR ((ttax.description LIKE '%driver%')) OR ((m.meta_value LIKE '%driver%')) OR ((wpdu_posts.post_excerpt LIKE '%driver%')) OR (((cmt.comment_content LIKE '%driver%')) AND cmt.comment_approved = '1') OR ((u.display_name LIKE '%driver%')) )) AND (wpdu_posts.post_password = '') AND wpdu_posts.post_type IN ('page', 'post', 'videogallery') AND (wpdu_posts.post_status = 'publish') GROUP BY wpdu_posts.ID" string(541) "(((wpdu_posts.post_title LIKE '%driver%') OR (wpdu_posts.post_content LIKE '%driver%'))) OR ((tter.name LIKE '%driver%')) OR ((tter.slug LIKE '%driver%')) OR ((ttax.description LIKE '%driver%')) OR ((m.meta_value LIKE '%driver%')) OR ((wpdu_posts.post_excerpt LIKE '%driver%')) OR (((cmt.comment_content LIKE '%driver%')) AND cmt.comment_approved = '1') OR ((u.display_name LIKE '%driver%')) )) AND (wpdu_posts.post_password = '') AND wpdu_posts.post_type IN ('page', 'post', 'videogallery') AND (wpdu_posts.post_status = 'publish')"
```

What is wrong. Why I can't get this to work?

Update: **I believe that this is the full query which is generated**

```
SELECT DISTINCT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wpdu_posts.* FROM wpdu_posts LEFT JOIN wpdu_hdflvvideoshare LEFT JOIN wpdu_term_relationships AS trel ON (wpdu_posts.ID = trel.object_id) LEFT JOIN wpdu_term_taxonomy AS ttax ON ( ( ttax.taxonomy = 'category' OR ttax.taxonomy = 'post_tag' OR ttax.taxonomy = 'post_format' OR ttax.taxonomy = 'bp_member_type' OR ttax.taxonomy = 'bp-email-type' ) AND trel.term_taxonomy_id = ttax.term_taxonomy_id) LEFT JOIN wpdu_terms AS tter ON (ttax.term_id = tter.term_id) LEFT JOIN wpdu_comments AS cmt ON ( cmt.comment_post_ID = wpdu_posts.ID ) LEFT JOIN wpdu_postmeta AS m ON (wpdu_posts.ID = m.post_id) LEFT JOIN wpdu_users AS u ON (wpdu_posts.post_author = u.ID) WHERE 1=1 AND ( ( (((wpdu_hdflvvideoshare.description LIKE '%driver%') OR (((wpdu_posts.post_title LIKE '%driver%') OR (wpdu_posts.post_content LIKE '%driver%'))) OR ((tter.name LIKE '%driver%')) OR ((tter.slug LIKE '%driver%')) OR ((ttax.description LIKE '%driver%')) OR ((m.meta_value LIKE '%driver%')) OR ((wpdu_posts.post_excerpt LIKE '%driver%')) OR (((cmt.comment_content LIKE '%driver%')) AND cmt.comment_approved = '1') OR ((u.display_name LIKE '%driver%')) )) AND (wpdu_posts.post_password = '') AND wpdu_posts.post_type IN ('page', 'post', 'videogallery') AND (wpdu_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wpdu_posts.post_type = 'attachment' OR wpdu_posts.post_status = 'draft') GROUP BY wpdu_posts.ID) AND post_type != 'revision') AND post_status != 'future' ORDER BY wpdu_posts.post_title LIKE '%driver%' DESC, wpdu_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

Comment: What is the full sql command that is failing? Your var_dump is not a completed sql statement

Comment: How can I see full query?

Comment: var_dump the variable that contains the whole sql statement.

Comment: I've tried `echo $wpdb->last_query;` but I got something strange. This: `SELECT * FROM wpdu_posts WHERE (post_type = 'page' AND post_status = 'publish') ORDER BY wpdu_posts.post_parent,menu_order ASC`

Comment: Don't ask to dump the last query... It doesn't appear to be yours. Dump the variable that contains the sql statement you are sending... your var_dump doesn't have a full sql statement in it, and therefore the statement will fail.

Comment: I've updated my question with the query which I see.

Comment: if you copy-paste that into your db directly, does it run?

Comment: I get error: `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE 1=1 AND ( ( (((wpdu_hdflvvideoshare.description LIKE '%driver%') OR (((wpd' at line 1`

Comment: there ya go, then... you've got sooo many parenthesis in that statement, I'm not about to try to find the error, but I guarantee you it is because of that.

Comment: Ok, but how to find the first part of the query which is from WP core? My code which I posted in the question got just one pair of open/closed parenthesis...

Comment: No... the sql code you dumped from your var_dump shows a billion parenthesis's...

Comment: As I said I didn't put them and I don't know from where they came..

Comment: It's your code. If you don't know where those came from them you don't understand your code

Comment: Sure I don't understand it. If I was .. I would not ask a question in the SO. My code is in my question. 90% from the query is coming from wordpress not from my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query has a `GROUP BY` condition inside the `WHERE` clause. There may be other issues, but that will certainly ensure that you get a syntax error.